# Text file data where I need to use dictionary having duplicates to get total Price, total items for order 1211. and same for 4322

Tags: c#

```
OrderID=1211, OrderName=’Alice’, OrderDate= ‘15-10-2019’ //- row1
OrderID=1211, ItemID=1, ItemName=’Laptop’, ItemCompany=’Dell’, ItemPrice=’40000’ //row2
OrderID=1211, ItemID=2, ItemName=’Mouse’, ItemCompany=’Logitech’, ItemPrice=’5000’ //3
OrderID=4322, OrderName=’Ben’, OrderDate= ‘1-10-2019’//4
OrderID=4322, ItemID=1, ItemName=’Laptop’, ItemCompany=’Microsoft’, ItemPrice=’40000’//5
OrderID=4322, ItemID=2, ItemName= ‘Keyboard’, ItemCompany=’Microsoft’, ItemPrice=’12000’ //6
```

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> yourDic = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:Probb.txt");

        bool first = true;
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {

            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] data = line.Split(',');

            if (first == false)
            {

                if (!yourDic.ContainsKey(line.Split(',')[0]))
                {
                   yourDic.Add(line.Split(',')[0], line.Split(',')[1] + "," + line.Split(',')[2]);
                }
                else if (!yourDic.ContainsKey(line.Split(',')[1]))
                {
                    yourDic.Add(line.Split(',')[1], line.Split(',')[2] + "," + line.Split(',')[3] + "," + line.Split(',')[4]);
                }
                else
                {
                    yourDic.Add(line.Skip(1), line.Split(',')[2] + "," + line.Split(',')[3] + "," + line.Split(',')[4]);

                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);

            }
            first = false;
        }


        foreach (KeyValuePair<dynamic, dynamic> kvp in yourDic)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0},\n {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }

    }

    }
}
```

Thanks for trying. I am new to C# and don't know how to access the specific data. output: OrderId:1211 Order Name=Alice, Total Id=2, Total Price=45000

Comment: Please update your question so that it contains exactly which output you are expecting for your provided example input. That will help us help you.

Comment: If I get your data right, it contains two types of data: Orders (identified by OrderID, with properties OrderName and OrderDate) and Items (identified by OrderID plus ItemID, with properties ItemName, ItemCompany and ItemPrice). Having both types of data in one dictionary seems to be not an optimal choice. Also, consider createing classes for these two data types.

Comment: Okay, I will remember doing so, Thanks.

Comment: Side note: put `line.Split(',')` into a variable then you don't need to keep calling it. Also `sr` needs a `using` to dispose it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Dictionary must have a unique key, you need to save all order items in the same key. If I got you question correctly you want to get sum of item price for each `OrderId`.

By this way I think this should work:

```cs
public class Order
{
    public string OrderName { get; set; }

    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    public int ItemPrice { get; set; }
}

var dictItems = new Dictionary<string, Order>();
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").ToList();

foreach (var line in allLines)
{
    var splitLine = line.Split(',');
    if (dictItems.ContainsKey(splitLine[0]))
        dictItems[splitLine[0]].OrderItems.Add(new OrderItem()
        {
            ItemId = int.Parse(splitLine[1].Split('=')[1]),
            ItemPrice = int.Parse(splitLine[4].Split('=')[1].Replace("’", ""))
        });
    else
        dictItems.Add(splitLine[0],
            new()
            {
                OrderName = splitLine[1].Split('=')[1].Replace("’", ""),
                OrderDate = splitLine[2].Split('=')[1].Replace("’", ""),
                OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>()
            });
}

foreach (var dictItem in dictItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" {0},\n OrderName: {1} \n Total: {2} \n TotalPrice: {3}", dictItem.Key, dictItem.Value.OrderName, dictItem.Value.OrderItems.Count, dictItem.Value.OrderItems.Sum(x => x.ItemPrice));
}
```

Of course, you need to check the real data for preventing exception in convert string to int.

Comment: I need the first line for order name and need an item id count. Thanks saeed

Comment: @John_Martin Answer updated.

Comment: Lord and savior! Thanks

Comment: Any tips from where to learn c#

Comment: you can read and follow the c# specs from Microsoft, there are lots of online sources on udemy, linkedin learning etc. or you can buy a c# book.

But don't forget learning c# is not enough you need to learn dotnet libraries. @John_Martin